# pandas DataFrame cut

Tags: python, pandas

i want to cut all the columns of Data Frame. When I print the result it show good result, but when I want to assign those values in new data frame it returns NaNs.[example of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJygT.png)

Comment: Please don't just give screenshots of code, it should be included in your question as properly formatted text. Please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: Provide snippets of input & output data. That will help us provide the appropriate solution (sometimes, there may be a better way of doing it than the way you are trying to do)

Comment: Thank you. This was the first question, I wil try to make better one next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to paste your code here for understanding proper solution of problem.

you can try to add one line of code:

```
slc=slc.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thank you verry much. I will make better question next time, this was the first one.